# 2 different url on same web site but not in open graph

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I have a web site with 2 different url, in these url I added open graph meta tag: appid, admins id etc but the first url had id opengraph and admin page and for second url I dont can make ad open graph and admin page

you can check with these url for verify

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bloo.it%2Fgallerie-foto%2Flucio-dalla  (this is ok)

but this no:
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bloo.it%2Fspettacolo-arte%2Fmusica%2Fmorte-lucio-dalla-ricordi-carriera-di-un-cantautore-indimenticabile.html

Comment: normally if I click on like button then open graph create a new fan page related to url but in second url this not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user has to Like your 2nd URL for it to appear in the Graph - or have a user post a custom action against it. Otherwise Facebook won't make it an object in the Open Graph.